# Escape character in jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, escaping

this is my first post, so if I do somenthing aganist the rules please let me know.

I have a problem in my jquery file with this statement:

```
        $('#temp').append(
                "<li class = 'list-group-item'><a href='others_profile.php?view=<?php echo $row['user']?>'>" 
                + array_users_found[i] + 
                "</a></li>");
```

Because the symbols '' around 'user' cause a problem I guess.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: This should not be a problem as the php gets parsed before anything else. Is this a php file or is your server set-up to process javascript files as php?

Comment: PHP does not usually run in plain `.js` JavaScript files (which is what you're presumably referring to with "jquery file").

Comment: I think you forgot the semicolon at the `echo` statement `<?php echo $row['user']; ?>`

Comment: @user3350731 that semicolon is optional

Comment: Try removing the quotes around `$row['user']` - and what is `array_users_found`? (Google results were 2, your question and something else). That's not a function I know of; where is that coming from?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. array_users_found is an array I've created. Yes, the file an .js JavaScript file. Unfortunately I can't remove the quotes around $row['user'] because they're essential for my external php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#temp').append(
    '<li class="list-group-item"><a href="others_profile.php?view=<?php echo urlencode($row['user']); ?>">' 
    + array_users_found[i] + 
    '</a></li>'
);
```

**Note**: The only way a PHP statement will be interpreted is if it exists within an HTML file that's processed by a PHP-enabled web server. Typically, these are files with the .html or .php extensions. Putting a PHP statement in a .js file for example won't work. The PHP interpreter won't parse a .js file.

**Additional Note**: If you want to incorporate PHP into your javascript, the simplest solution would be to move the code snippet into your HTML document, wherever it's needed. Alternatively, you can change your javascript file to a PHP file that serves javascript content by setting the response [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) appropriately before outputting anything. Ex:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/javascript'); ?>
// your javascript here ...
```

The downside to this approach is that you're adding the overhead of PHP to serve javascript and browsers may not cache the file because it's assumed to be dynamic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I have the same problem with it. Because the first ' make a match with the first ' in 'user' .

Comment: Then your PHP code isn't being interpreted. Can you explain where this javascript code exists or paste your full source?

Comment: This javascript code exists in an external .js file. External from the main html(in this case  with the .php extension) page. I'm trying to append this list to a div so that when I click on the link in the list appended another php file(in this case others_profile.php) is called

Comment: Ok there's your problem. See my added note to the answer above. Not enough room in comments to explain.